# Passing reference of reference to function argument (book v1)

Tags: rust, reference, heap-memory, stack-memory

In short, does passing reference A of another reference B to function parameter causing automatic dereference?

Here's the story...

When reading [stack & heap - complex example](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/the-stack-and-the-heap.html#a-complex-example), I am confused at the following explanation, please see img01 -> img02.

Since variable `e` is a reference to variable `d`, so the value of `e` is represented in `-> 9 (i read it as: go to memory address of d)`, this is ok.

But why does the parameter `f` of `baz` get value of "data address referred by `d`", instead of the value of `e`? I thought the value of `f` should be `-> 9` as well?

If `f` is what img02 says it is, then does it mean that "dereference" happened here automatically? Since `e` contains a reference to `d`, `d` contains a reference to some heap address, and the passing of `e` to `f` results in `f` has a reference to the heap address?

img01
[image: img01]

img02
[image: img02]

Comment: Maybe because f is declared as &i32 and the compiler is enable to silentlly cast &&i32 (type of e)  to &i32.

Comment: @JoëlHecht i think your comment makes sense, but this brings up another question; as far as i know, Box type is owned by d, and represented as "->(2^30) -2" in img02. So if f has the same value of "->(2^30) -2", than it looks like the same Box is owned by 2 variables?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a dereference is done automatically. This is called [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion).

This is the mechanism that allows for implicitly converting one reference to another. Some notable uses:

- `&&T` -> `&T`
- `&&&&&&&&T` -> `&T`
- `&Box<T>` -> `&T`
- `&Vec<T>` -> `&[T]`

See more explanation in the Rust book: [Treating Smart Pointers Like Regular References with the `Deref` Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html) or in the Rust reference: [Type Coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html).

Comment: thanks @kmdreko, i think `&Box<32> -> &i32` explains the case of `e -> f` in my question.